# Use headphones for radio on PC

Tags: headphones

I know this may sound stupid, but I haven't seen a single question regarding this.

I want to use my headphones to listen to radio (like the FM app on smartphones) on my computer. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Do you have an SDR or FM tuner device to use?

Comment: @dobey No, I don't

Comment: There are many FM tuner apps, but you will need hardware to use with them. Otherwise, if it's a specific station, many do have streams available via the Internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FM app on smartphones like "Radio FM" plays internet radio streams.  There are many internet radio apps for Linux and Ubuntu specifically like Gradio, Goodvibes, and even Rhythmbox will do it (although I don't love the Rhythmbox internet radio interface myself).